# Error "Illegal unit of measure" occuring when using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, incompatibility

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand*\sleep[3]{%
  \psframe[fillstyle=crosshatch*](6 #1 mul 37 sub 0.5)(6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5 5 #2 div add)
  \psframe[fillstyle=solid](6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5)(6 #1 mul 35 sub 5 0.5 #3 div add)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2,0.5)(4,1.3)
  \sleep{6.5}{4}{0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If the above code is compiled, the following error occurs:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   6
l.13   \sleep{6.5}{4}{0}
```

Why will the code not compile? (It is probably something trivial but I cannot see what the problem is.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify two things:

1. `\SpecialCoor` - indicates that you will be using coordinate representations other than Cartesian;
2. Use `!`-notation for Postscript-related coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks

\newcommand*\sleep[3]{%
  \psframe[fillstyle=crosshatch*](!6 #1 mul 37 sub 0.5)(!6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5 5 #2 div add)
  \psframe[fillstyle=solid](!6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5)(!6 #1 mul 35 sub 5 0.5 #3 div add)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2,0.5)(4,1.3)
  \SpecialCoor
  \sleep{6.5}{4}{0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is discussed in chapter **XI Other features** of the [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! I Guess I'm too tired; this is really basic PSTricks (and I should have seen this myself).

Answer (score 6):

Use `pstricks-add` instead and the `!` operator. However, your code doesn't work you have a division by zero. Use the operator `Div` instead of the default `div`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newcommand*\sleep[3]{%
  \psframe[fillstyle=crosshatch*](!6 #1 mul 37 sub 0.5)(!6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5 5 #2 div add)
  \psframe(!6 #1 mul 36 sub 0.5)(!6 #1 mul 35 sub 5 0.5 #3 Div add)%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2,0.5)(4,1.3)
  \sleep{6.5}{4}{0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Herbert. The division thing is because I made an error in the code. `:)`